# What does the rotation group of $\mathbb{\bar{Q}}^n$ look like?

Tags: geometry, rotations

There's a structural difference between the rotation groups of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$; in some abstract sense the former is 'small' (discrete?) while the latter is 'large'.  I suspect that part of the root of this is what might be called distance-closure: the distance between any two elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}$, whereas distances between two elements of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ aren't necessarily in $\mathbb{Q}$; in essence, rotations in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are transitive on $\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$, whereas rotations in $\mathbb{Q}^n$ aren't transitive on $\mathbb{QP}^{n-1}$ (for instance, there's no rotation of $\mathbb{Q^2}$ mapping the line $\langle t,0\rangle$ onto the line $\langle t,t\rangle$).

But there are intermediate fields between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ that are still distance-closed; in particular, the (real) algebraic closure of the rationals $\mathbb{\bar{Q}}\cap\mathbb{R}$ (I'm going to call this guy $\mathbb{\hat{Q}}$ in lieu of any better symbol) is.  Virtually all of classical geometry translates directly to $\mathbb{\hat{Q}}^n$, and we get the transitivity of rotations on $\mathbb{\hat{Q}P}^{n-1}$ mentioned above.  Is anything known about this group of rotations, and in particular — while it's obviously not as topologically nice as $O(n)$ since $\mathbb{\hat{Q}}$ isn't complete — is there a good structural sense in which it's 'larger' than the rotation group of $\mathbb{Q}^n$, beyond just the transitivity I mentioned above?

Comment: A few comments: I don't think there is anything discrete about the rotations in $\Bbb{Q}^n$. It should be easy to show that reflection w.r.t. hyperplanes through the origin determined by equations with rational coordinates generate a dense subgroup of $O_n(\Bbb{R})$. A second point is that it might also be interesting to look at $\bar{\Bbb{Q}}\cap\Bbb{R}$ instead of taking the entire algebraic closure.

Comment: (cont'd) But if we do look at it over $\bar{\Bbb{Q}}$, then we can give the group of matrices such that there transpose is equal to their inverse a structure over an algebraic variety. This has consequences in solvability of certain equations (like the lack of 45 degree rotation that you pointed out). If the equation has a solution over complex numbers it should (?) have a solution over $\bar{\Bbb{Q}}$ as well. Follows from Nullstellensatz I think(?).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Discrete may be the wrong word for it; I think the transitivity expresses the heart of what I was getting at, that in some sense there are 'fewer' rotations over $\mathbb{Q}$.  And you're right - I was actually thinking of $\mathbb{Q}\cap\mathbb{R}$ (is there a canonical name for that beast?); I'll fix that up.

Comment: (Whoops - that should be $\mathbb{\bar{Q}}\cap\mathbb{R}$ in the comment above, of course)

Comment: I think that $G=O_n(\hat{\Bbb{Q}})$ is divisible in the sense that all the matrices of $G$ have "roots" of all orders in $G$. Not sure, whether we can call this a "stuctural property" - just extrapolating from your example.

Comment: Yes, this group is divisible. Follows from Jordan normal form theorem.

Comment: What does “metrically closed” mean? ℝ is the minimal complete metric space including ℚ with its standard norm. There exist alternative norms for ℚ, but completions with respect to them are not “intermediate between ℚ and ℝ”; they are diverse.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi In this case, I don't mean closure in the topological 'all limits exist' sense, but closer in the operations sense: while it's not true that all distances between points in $\mathbb{Q^2}$ are in $\mathbb{Q}$ (consider, e.g., $\langle1,0\rangle$ and $\langle0,1\rangle$), it _is_ true that all distances between points in $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}^2$ are in $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi I'll revise the question to use slightly less loaded terminology, though, since 'metrically closed' really does strongly suggest topological completion...